# Cut and copy : Blackhole and default register assignment

Tags: key-bindings, cut-copy-paste, macvim, register

I currently have something like this in my vimrc. The reason i have this is because I do not want items to be copied to the default register when I delete or change.

```
"Copy the contents of delete to the black hole register
nnoremap dd "_dd
nnoremap d "_d
vnoremap d "_d
"Copy the contents of yank to the black hole register
nnoremap c "_c
nnoremap C "_C
```

Now lately i felt the need of adding a cut command as well which deletes and yank. I understand by default Vim does not have a delete but it has a cut command. However i have customised it to my liking. I wanted to know if there was a way for me to cut text that would work with the above keybinding. I tried doing this

```
"*dd
```

but that does not work and I guess that's because dd above gets mapped to `"_dd`
Any suggestions on how I can accomplish a cut while maintaining my current shortcuts ?

Comment: wouldn't mapping your shortcut to `dd` work? like `nnoremap #2 dd` to map <F2> key to delete current line as well as yank

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, I think your first mapping is unnecessary. Since the second `d` is in operator mode, it does not get remapped to `"_d`, so it maps out to `"_dd`. Secondly, you could do this:

```
nnoremap d "_d
nnoremap D "_D

nnoremap "*d "*d
nnoremap "*D "*D
```

This works since it uses `noremap`. Of course, you can change the register this yanks to, or the keystrokes you use to call it. For example, you could do

```
nnoremap "*d d
nnoremap "*D D
```

To make it yank to the unnamed register.